# Virtual Device is not launching in Android Studio

Tags: android

**I am using android studio (version 1.0.1) when is try to launch my virtual device is gives me an error.**

[image: Cannot launch AVD in emulator]

**I have these setting in my Virtual Device**

[image: Virtual Devices]

**I have following installations in my android SDK.**

[image: SDK Setting]
[image: Extra Setting]

**I have installed Intel HAXM but it gives me that error. When I run my x86 device it gives error but when i launch amr device is get start but too slow and did not respond in the end 
My machince specs are:
 - Intel Corei3 1.70
 - 4GB RAM
 - 500 GB Hard Drive
Kindly give me solution**

Answer (score 0):

Enable Intel Virtualization Technology(also known as Intel VT-x).The virtualization extensions may be labeledVirtualization Extensions, Vanderpool or various other names depending on the OEM and system BIOS.